# Regression line

Tags: regression

**A random sample of size $n$ from a bivariate distribution is denoted by $(x_r,y_r), r=1,2,3,...,n$. Show that if the regression line of $y$ on $x$ passes through the origin of its scatter diagram then**
$$\bar y\sum^n_{r=1} x_r^2=\bar x \sum^n_{r=1} x_r y_r$$ where $(\bar x,\bar y)$ is the mean point of the sample.

I don't really know how to begin. I am aware the line equation is $b=\frac{y}{x}=\frac{\sum xy-\frac{\sum x\sum y}{n}}{\sum x^2-\frac{(\sum x)^2}{n}}$

Not sure what to do next.

Comment: If it passes through the origin, then $a=0$.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the OLS estimators are
$$
\hat{\beta}_0 = \bar{Y}_n - \hat{\beta}_1\bar{X}_n, \quad \hat{\beta}_1 = \frac{\sum X_i Y_i-n\bar{X}\bar{Y}}{\sum X_i^2 - n\bar{X}^2},
$$
because the line passes through the origin, you have that $\hat{\beta}_0 = 0 = \bar{Y} - \hat{\beta}_1\bar{X}$, thus
$$
\frac{\bar{Y}}{\bar{X}} = \frac{\sum X_i Y_i-n\bar{X}\bar{Y}}{\sum X_i^2 - n\bar{X}^2},
$$
or
$$
\bar{Y}\sum X_i^2 - \bar{Y}n\bar{X}^2=\bar{X}\sum X_i Y_i -n\bar{Y}\bar{X}^2,
$$
hence
$$
\bar{Y}\sum X_i^2=\bar{X}\sum X_i Y_i .
$$

Comment: Can you tell me how did you decided which is the intercept?

Comment: It is a matter of derivation, rather than "decision". If you solve $\min_{\beta} \sum (y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1x_i)^2$, then you'll get that the OLS of the intercept is $\bar{y}-\hat{\beta}_1\bar{x}$.

Comment: Just one last thing. What is the variable $\beta_0$ that you used? Moreover can you please provide a proof for the intercept? (I am not that good in statistics to carry out the operation you suggested)

Comment: You can find [here](https://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic515975.files/OLSDerivation.pdf)  a full proof.